# Twilio: Localized SIP URIs

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to manually connect our SIP Domain enpoints to the ie1 region which is close to our UK office using:

```
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/sending-sip#localized-sip-uris
```

Which states as follows:

> Localized SIP URIs
>
> If you wish to manually connect to a specific geographic region that
>   is closest to the location of your communications infrastructure, you
>   may do so by pointing your communications infrastructure to any of the
>   following localized SIP URIs:
>
> ```
> {example}.sip.us1.twilio.com (North America Virginia)
> {example}.sip.us2.twilio.com (North America Oregon)
> {example}.sip.ie1.twilio.com (Europe Ireland)
> {example}.sip.de1.twilio.com (Europe Frankfurt) (Coming Soon)
> {example}.sip.sg1.twilio.com (Asia Pacific Singapore)
> {example}.sip.jp1.twilio.com (Asia Pacific Tokyo)
> {example}.sip.br1.twilio.com (South America São Paulo)
> {example}.sip.au1.twilio.com (Asia Pacific Sydney)
> ```

However I don't see how I can use these to send the traffic to the local region as the SIP enpoints seem to require us1 region.

Overall I'm trying to reduce 1-2 seconds of call delay when using SIP in the UK.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid that when you are using [Twilio's SIP Registration you can currently only register in the US1 region](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/sip-registration#sip-register). These localised SIP URIs are currently used for [Twilio's SIP Trunking](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sip-trunking) product.