# How to avoid twilio error 32011 (Error communicating with SIP communications infrastructure)

Tags: twilio, sip

I have created a backend system which utilizes Twilio. The backend and the VoIP clients are both localised in Europe. The system sometimes experiences 32011 errors (Error communicating with your SIP communications infrastructure). Which I believe is mainly caused by the fact that the 
twilio voice sip domain is located at Virginia US.

The problem is that according to this post:      [Twilio: Localized SIP URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47137443/twilio-localized-sip-uris)
,there is no way to change the region or create a voice domain at de1 region.

Is there any solution to this problem, by keep using twilio?

More details concerning this error may be found at the link below:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/32011

Answer (score 1):

With SIP domains, your clients are probably not shutting down their SIP clients when they are closing their laptops. This would remove their existing registration entry.

You can set the client SIP Registration timer to the minimum of 600 seconds (a setting on your SIP clients), which will timeout their registration entires after 10 minutes rather then the default 1 hour, which will reduce the frequency of that error message.